# Using QT5 how can I print a QTablewidget and scale a table to fit onto one side of an A4 sheet

Tags: html, printing, qt5

I have written a QT5 application that creates a monthly rota/timesheet based on various inputs.  It generates a csv file that I can use excel to read and print. I can use libreoffice to print this onto a single A4 sheet.
However what I would really like to do is to use qt to print the table directly to the printer.

I am afraid that I am confused as to how best to go about trying to achieve this.  I have used html with a QTextDocument to successfully print out the rota/timesheet. However the result ends up on two pages rather then one.  I print it out in landscape mode.  I think that it would be good to scale the height of the document down to fit on one page.

```
void ViewEditRotaDialog::m_printButtonSlot()
{
  QString strStream;
  QTextStream out(&strStream);

  const int rowCount = m_tableWidget->rowCount();
  const int columnCount = m_tableWidget->columnCount();

  out <<  "<html>\n"
  "<head>\n"
  "<meta Content=\"Text/html; charset=Windows-1251\">\n"
  <<  QString("<title>%1</title>\n").arg("ROTA")
  <<  "</head>\n"
  "<body bgcolor=#ffffff link=#5000A0>\n"
  "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>\n";

  // headers
  out << "<thead><tr bgcolor=#f0f0f0>";
  for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++)
    out << QString("<th>%1</th>").
        arg(m_tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(column)->text());
  out << "</tr></thead>\n";

  // data table
  for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
  {
    out << "<tr>";
    for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++)
    {
      QString data 
      m_tableWidget->item(row,column)->text().simplified();
      out << QString("<td bkcolor=0>%1</td>").
                 arg((!data.isEmpty()) ? data :  QString("&nbsp;"));
    }
    out << "</tr>\n";
  }
  out <<  "</table>\n"
            "</body>\n"
            "</html>\n";

  QTextDocument *document = new QTextDocument();
  document->setHtml(strStream);
  QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
  printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);
  printer.setPageMargins(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,QPrinter::Millimeter);
  printer.setFullPage(true);

  QPrintDialog *dialog = new QPrintDialog(&printer, NULL);
  if (dialog->exec() != QDialog::Accepted)
    return;

  document->print(&printer);
  delete document;
}
```

I have seen other examples using QPainter and trying to scale the output.
Should I be doing this and using drawcontents() or should I be using a completely different method?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to have a play with using painter and drawContents().  I was pleased that I could get it to do what I needed with minimum effort.  I dont yet fully understand the details of how this works, but I will look into it in more detail later.  It might be that I will need to enhance this, but it looks very good for what I need.  Simply put it looks like I just needed to change the scales to make it do what I required. Not ever having used QT before to do printing I did'nt really know how best to do this. But I am happy with the result.

I replaced the code under 
    `QTextDocument *document = new QTextDocument();`
with

```
`
document->setHtml(strStream);

QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);
printer.setPageMargins(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,QPrinter::Millimeter);
printer.setFullPage(true);

QPrintDialog *dialog = new QPrintDialog(&printer, NULL);
if (dialog->exec() != QDialog::Accepted)
  return;

QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&printer);

double xscale = printer.pageRect().width() / document->size().width();
double yscale = printer.pageRect().height() / document->size().height();
painter.translate(printer.paperRect().x() + printer.pageRect().width() / 2,
                printer.paperRect().y() + printer.pageRect().height() / 2);
painter.scale(xscale, yscale);
painter.translate(-document->size().width() / 2,
                                     -document->size().height() / 2);

document->drawContents(&painter);
painter.end();
delete document;
}`
```

This may not be the best answer, but it works so far.